# What is the point in taking Monte Carlo realizations of a data set?

Tags: statistics, random, monte-carlo, error-propagation

Let's say I have a dataset that is 100 elements long,

$X = \{x_0...x_{100}\}$

and I do 1,000 Monte Carlo realizations of the data, $X_j, 0\leq j \leq1000$, sampling 10 points each time.

If I then compute the variance (or any other estimator) on those ten points, and do that for every realization, I can then use that to tell me about the variance of the whole dataset.

$Var(X) \approx \dfrac{\sum_{j=0}^{1000}Var(X_j)}{1000}$

So, why would I do this? If I take those 1,000 variances, and average them, shouldn't it just converge to the variance of the whole set, if I were to measure it once? Is the only reason to do it this way to be able to measure the error on the computed variance?

Comment: Without going into details, I think your text or instructor is trying to get you ready to understand bootstrapping and other 'comupter-age' inferential methods that do not assume a particular population distribution. (Notice that no assumption is made about the distribution of your $x_i.$ Typically these involve the kind of simulated 're-sampling' described here. One way to gain faith in simulation-based procedures is to try them out in situations where you can also get the answer analytically. The answer from simulation and the analytic answer should agree.

Comment: @BruceET I see. Indeed, the data I am working with is not known to be from a particular distribution, so that makes sense. Also, this is not from any instructional material, it is a method being used in a published paper that I am reading. I'm trying to recreate some results and I don't think I'm doing the resampling correctly.